# Aspose LINQ text trims of

Tags: java, mysql, linq, aspose, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a LINQ Reporting Engine word file. Which has A field <<[ABC]>> . And its getting value from MySQL database. 
The Field is a field that displays comments.Now the field type in SQL is Long-text so it can store large number of words. The problem is when a report is generated the field <<[ABC]>> has the text that is cut off in other words it only printing up-to few character around 380 . My question here is , there any specific limit that LINQ filed can display. And what can do to make all the text print with out any limit?

Comment: How this query relates to Aspose? Are you using Aspose.Words or Aspose.Cells or any other Aspose API? Please mention the Aspose API, you are using for further investigation of your issue. Thanks for your cooperation in this regard and have a good day. ---- Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: I am using LINQ Reporting Engine , Thanq for response  .https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Template+Syntax .

Comment: Thanks for the further information. We will update you asap.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate <<[ABC]>> with long text. There is no limit for number of characters. You can simply test it using following code example. Create a text file e.g. "text.txt" with some text and execute the following code.

```
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder();
builder.Write("<<[ABC]>>"); 

ReportingEngine engine = new ReportingEngine();

engine.BuildReport(builder.Document, File.ReadAllText(MyDir + "text.txt"), "ABC");
builder.Document.Save(MyDir + "18.4.docx");
```

I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.